# How to throw a warning if threshold value exceeds in foundry code repositories

Tags: pyspark, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories, foundry-python-transform

I have taken an input dataset and did some transformations on it, then wrote it into the output dataset.

I have built this output dataset, and now I have to take the time taken to build the output dataset and compare that with a threshold time provided. If the build duration is greater than the threshold given, I have to throw a warning or alert

For example
Build time : 120 minutes
Threshold : 100 min
As Build time is more than threshold it should throw a warning

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Data Health check to receive this kind of alert. From the dataset preview page click the Health tab. Under the Add Checks section click Time and then Job Duration. This will open a modal dialog where you can set the threshold time and create the check.

Once the check is created you will receive an email whenever a build on this dataset lasts longer than the specified threshold time.